# Haskell: where is Data.Numbers.Primes library?

Tags: haskell, primes

I tried importing Data.Numbers.Primes

```
import Data.Numbers.Primes
```

runhaskell gave me:

```
5.hs:1:8:
    Could not find module `Data.Numbers.Primes'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

ghci gave me:

```
<no location info>:
    Could not find module `Data.Numbers.Primes'
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
```

I tried to install Data.Numbers.Primes through cabal, but I got:

```
cabal update
...
cabal install Data
cabal: There is no package named 'Data'.
You may need to run 'cabal update' to get the latest list of available
packages.
cabal install Data.Numbers.Primes
cabal: The file does not exist 'Data.Numbers.Primes'.
```

help?

Comment: [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=Data.Numbers.Primes) is a good search engine for stuff like this.

Comment: Also, start using stack to save yourself from dependency hell issues.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard newbie here, can you elaborate please?

Comment: Ah yes, well the further along you go, the more likely you will run into the transitivity problem we call "dependency hell". Check out stack for a solution. https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/tree/master/doc

Comment: use the [arithmoi package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.4.1.3/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Primes-Sieve.html#v:primes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package you're looking for is called [`primes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/primes).

There's no rule that the package will be called the same as its top-level module name. Typically, packages put themselves under whatever makes sense, but that's pretty much arbitrary. When in doubt, [Hackage search](https://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=Primes) helps.