# Module can not be imported after installing via cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal

I tried using the primes module in Haskell and after running

```
$ cabal install primes 

Resolving dependencies...
Notice: installing into a sandbox located at /home/christoph/.cabal-sandbox
Downloading primes-0.2.1.0...
Configuring primes-0.2.1.0...
Building primes-0.2.1.0...
Installed primes-0.2.1.0
```

I tried making a file with

```
import Data.Numbers.Primes
```

at the top, but every attempt to load it failed with the error message:

```
Could not find module ‘Data.Numbers.Primes’
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

The question: what am I missing here? there must be something wrong with this way of using it right?

After reading [Haskell: where is Data.Numbers.Primes library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424064/haskell-where-is-data-numbers-primes-library) I also tried:

```
import Data.Primes
import primes
import Primes
```

but none of them worked.

Thank you in advance, any help is most welcome

Comment: That says it was installed into a sandbox. Are you compiling with cabal in that sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are installing the primes package to a sandbox, you will need to run the compiler with awareness of the sandbox. `cabal` offers the `exec` command for this, so e.g.

```
echo import Data.Numbers.Primes >foo.hs
cabal exec ghci foo.hs
```

from within the sandbox should work.